# Sleep for specific function only c++ borland

Tags: c++, function, timer, sleep, borland-c++

Is there any way to do something like:

```
void f(){

sleep(500) 

}
```

but it will influence only on the function f, means, only f will sleep and not all the program.

more details: f is a timer function

I'm using in c++ builder borland (bcb6)

Any suggestions?

Comment: is your application multi-threaded?

Comment: Yes. it's multi-threaded. any advice?

Comment: then sleep will cause the current thread to be suspended when sleep encountered. Others threads ill be executing at that time

Comment: but I call for sleep from the event of timer, and there is at least 2 therads acts parallel and actually when I put sleep(500) something on the program become incorrect. do you have any assumption regarding? any idea for solution?

Comment: Why sleep in the timer function!? Can you not set the timer interval a bit longer instead?

Comment: 1. Sleep inside timer is actually stopping `WinProc` function!!! actively stopping your application (the threads may run but the application freeze so if you are drawing any state it will not be updated during that time giving illusion of threads stopped too)  2. I hope you mean by threads real threads created with `CreateThread(...)` and not just parallel VCL timer components (those are not parallel at all !!!). Instead You can use timer to schedule the function `f()` to some or new thread if the previous processing is already finished. You should return from evens as fast as you can.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes. it's multi-threaded. any advice?

Just use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for), which will suspend only the thread on which it was called.

Comment: Can I call it from the timer method? because I perfer not call it from the thread's method. and also I have two threads so how can I use it for sleep only for specific thread (one of both threads)

Comment: @user687459 It's not a "method". It's a free function in the namespace `this_thread`. And it will automatically work only on the thread that executes that line.

Comment: but that line is in frame of timer and two threads are working parallel at that's time, and actually I would like that only this function will sleep for 500 ms and other threads will alive. this time I think is as part of the main thread.